# Modify path name when saving with PIL

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I am extracting RGB channels  from images and saving them as grayscale png files, but I have trouble saving them. Here is my code:

```
listing = os.listdir(path1)    
for f in listing:
    im = Image.open(path1 + f)
    red, green, blue = im.split()
    red = red.convert('LA')
    green = green.convert('LA')
    blue = blue.convert('LA')
    red.save(path2 + f + 'r', 'png')
    green.save(path2 + f + 'g', 'png')
    blue.save(path2 + f + 'b','png')
```

Where `path1` and `path2` are image folder and save destinations respectively. What I want to do is to save the b&w version of color channel of `img.png` to 
`imgr.png`, `imgg.png`, `imgb.png`, but what I get with this code is `img.pngr`, `img.pngg`, `img.pngb`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This isn't really to do with images, it's how to modify parts of a path. Strip away everything in the question and focus maybe one or two lines of code. See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this as follows:

```
import os

listing = os.listdir(path1)    

for f in listing:
    im = Image.open(os.path.join(path1, f))

    red, green, blue = im.split()
    red = red.convert('LA')
    green = green.convert('LA')
    blue = blue.convert('LA')

    file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(f)

    red.save(os.path.join(path2, "{}r.png".format(file_name))
    green.save(os.path.join(path2, "{}g.png".format(file_name))
    blue.save(os.path.join(path2, "{}b.png".format(file_name))
```

I would recommend you make use of the [`os.path.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path.join#os.path.split) and [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path.join#os.path.join) functions when working with paths and filenames.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to split the filename from the extension.

```
import os
filename = path2 + f # Consider using os.path.join(path2, f) instead
root, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
```

Then you can combine them correctly again doing:

```
filename = root + "r" + ext
```

Now `filename` would be `imgr.png` instead of `img.pngr`.